# How do I stop Windows XP showing the login screen after a few minutes of inactivity?

Tags: windows-xp, login

After leaving Windows XP alone for a few minutes, it shows the user login screen.

I use Windows XP in VMs, so I’d rather switch this feature off.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aha:

1. Control Panel
2. If necessary, “Switch to Classic View”
3. Display
4. Screen Saver tab
5. Uncheck “On resume, display Welcome screen”

Props to [Jimmy Greystone on CNET forums](http://forums.cnet.com/5208-6142_102-0.html?threadID=316610).